# vtk does not show the whole bounding-box

Tags: c++, camera, vtk

I am displaying some spheres and around this spheres there is a bounding-box:

```
vtkActor* Handler::createBoundingBox(double xMin, double xMax, 
                                 double yMin, double yMax, 
                                 double zMin, double zMax)
{
    vtkOutlineSource *bb = vtkOutlineSource::New();

    // set the bb
    bb->SetBounds(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax);

    // bb -> mapper
    vtkPolyDataMapper *mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(bb->GetOutputPort());

    // mapper -> actor
    vtkActor *actor = vtkActor::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    return actor;
}
```

when I start my application, some corners, the lines in the back and everything in the bounding-box is not shown.
But after I interact (rotate a bit using the mouse), everything is shown correctly.

Is there a method I should call before starting everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling ResetCamera() on the vtkRenderer